# Getting issues when trying to fetch attribute value in javascript controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to get component attribute value in javascript controller. I'm not getting that instead it is saying Undefined when set javascript alert.
Below is my code. Please provide any suggestions.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name = "buttonLabel" type="String" default="Search"/>
    <aura:attribute name = "newLabel" type="String" default="New Button"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isNewAvaialble" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="carTypes" type="String[]" default="Luxury Car,Standard Car,Van"/>
    <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center" >
        <lightning:layoutitem padding="around-medium">
            <lightning:select name="selectItem" aura:Id="carType" label="All Types" variant="label-hidden" value="">
               <option value="" text="All Types"></option>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.carTypes}" var="car">
                 <option value="{!car}" text="{!car}"></option>
                </aura:iteration>                
            </lightning:select>
        </lightning:layoutitem>
        <lightning:layoutitem padding="around-medium"> 
            <lightning:button  variant="brand" label="{!v.buttonLabel}" onclick="{!c.onSearchClick}"></lightning:button>
            <lightning:button  variant="Neutral" label="ToggleButton" onclick="{!c.togglebutton}"></lightning:button>


            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isNewAvailable}">
                <lightning:button  variant="Neutral" label="{#v.newLabel}"></lightning:button>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    you can not edit the record
                </aura:set>
            </aura:if> 
        </lightning:layoutitem>    
    </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

Controller JS:

```
({
    onSearchClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.handleOnSearchClick(component, event, helper);       
    },
    togglebutton: function(component, event, helper) {
        var curvalue = component.get("v.isNewAvailable");
        alert(curvalue);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a typo in your attribute name.

The attribute is defined on your component as ***isNewAvaialble***. Whereas you are trying to access it in JS using the name ***isNewAvailable*** (notice the difference in the spelling here).

Change it on component as below and you should be good to fetch the value.

```
<aura:attribute name="isNewAvailable" type="boolean" default="false"/>
```

Comment: If I had one cent for every minute I have spent chasing down typos like that one....